# Add react component to html element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a containerElement and a react component. I want to add the react component into the containerElement. Is there a way I can do it? I have tried containerElement .appendChild(), but not working.

```
const containerElement = document.getElementById(divId);
React component: <ReactComponent></ReactComponnet>
```

Comment: Use `ReactDOM.render` https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render

Answer (score 2):

```
ReactDOM.render(<ReactComponent/>, document.getElementById(divId));
```

Comment: You also need to `import ReactDOM from "react-dom"` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Following the React lifecycles, you shouldn't have to insert the component into your parent component (containerElement). The react component should be inserted in the normal flow as a child or grandchild of the parent component.

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to handle the case where you are getting the `DOMElement` outside the normal flow of the React lifecycle. For that you can use refs.

For example below, define the component you're trying to insert somewhere in the render lifecycle of your container. No matter how nested the child is, you can "get" the child DOM element just like you are trying to do with `document.getElementById` from your question.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.myRef = React.createRef();
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <FunctionComponent ref={this.myRef} />
      );
   }
}
```

Hope this helps